# How to import applicationContext.xml and Bean from external jar to @SpringBootTest?

Tags: java, spring

I have a test:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {
...
}
```

And i have external jar, which has class MyService (with @Service) and applicationContext.xml (creates beans-args for MyService). How to import them to MyTest? I want to check, that my bean is created.

Comment: Why, specifically, does this external jar have an XML configuration in it?

Comment: I don't know reason for it)

Answer (score 0):

The result of my investigations:

1. Bean from external jar will be automatically create by Spring.
2. Application context can be import like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest{
...
}
```